# How can I access a specific column of a .csv file that doesn't have column headers, using OleDB?

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

I have a .csv file that I am trying to load into a DataGridView. First, I have a combobox that will hold all of the values in the first column of the .csv. The user will select one item from the combobox, and my code is supposed to then search for that item, retrieve the other elements from the same row, and place them into a datagridview. From the examples I've seen, there is always a header in each column that can be referenced, however the .csv file I am working with will have no headers. How can I reference these columns within a OleDbCommand?

I've tried pulling the whole file into a dataset, and then manipulating the dataset to use just the first column, but without column headers I'm not certain how to actually pull specific columns.

```
                {
                    myConn.Open();
                    var objCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [myFileName.csv]", myConn);
                    OleDbDataAdapter objDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                    objDA.SelectCommand = objCmd;
                    DataSet ObjDataSet = new DataSet();
                    objDA.Fill(ObjDataSet);
                    DefaultSelector.DataSource = ObjDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[];
                }
```

With the above I get an error: "Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource".

I've tried using `Rows[0]` instead of `Columns[0]`, attempting to get the first item of each row, but it seems that i would also need to include a `["HeaderName"]` following it, which doesn't exist in the file.

Is it possible to just pull one column from the .csv? If not, how can I pull 1 column from the DataSet?

Comment: `myDGV.DataSource = ObjDataSet;`  Hide the other columns or do not use `SELECT *` if you do not want all the columns

Answer (score 0):

Very late on this, but...
Just use **F1**, **F2**, **F3**, ... as column names in the query.

```
select F3 from MyFile.CSV where F1='some_id'
```

I think the 'F' stands for *Field*.